# How to access public variables from another View Model

Tags: datacontext, avaloniaui

I have a public variable in one View Model that I want to be able to access (get and set) from another Views code-behind. I have a MainWindowViewModel and a SettingsViewModel. The code-behind I want to be able to access this variable already has a DataContext definition for MainWindowViewModel, which I think may be the problem, since as far as I know I cant define two DataContext for the same view.

As an example, SettingsViewModel has a variable called LowerLimit which I have bound to the selected value of a NumericUpDown. I initialized a variable to hold the DataContext as SettingsViewModel so I can access the variable in that ViewModel. I did this with the code

```
var settingsContext = DataContext as SettingsViewModel;
```

But for some reason this throwing a NullRefereceException, saying settingsContext is null.

SettingsViewModel.cs:

```
public double[] LowerLimit { get; set; } = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };  //LowerLimit NumericUpDown
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}

private void Run_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) //Button click event
{
   ...
   var settingsContext = DataContext as SettingsViewModel;
   lowerLimitCol = (int)settingsContext.LowerLimit[generalIndex];
}
```

I have only provided the relevant code to the problem. If I am mistaken and more code is required to answer the question then I can provide it.

Expected result: settingsContext gets DataContext from SettingsViewModel, allowing me to access the LowerLimit variable from MainWindow.xaml.cs and assign it to a local variable.

Actual result: NullReferenceException, settingsContext was null

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing your `DataContext` to an instance of `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

And then you're trying to cast `DataContext` to `SettingsViewModel`:

```
var settingsContext = DataContext as SettingsViewModel;
```

This obviously won't work because you set `DataContext` to an instance of `MainWindowViewModel` and not `SettingsViewModel`.

One way around this would be to expose your `SettingsViewModel` as a property of `MainWindowViewModel` so you could then do:

```
var settingsContext = ((MainWindowViewModel)DataContext).Settings
```